# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo IndexOutOfBoundsException Invalid index 0, size is 0

Tags: android, google-maps, debugging, indexoutofboundsexception

my code shows error in logcat out of bound exception with index 0 size 0.
When I open this activity app crashes. I don't know what is issue please help me to fix this. Thanks
This is google map which shows location of user

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_map);
    initCompnent();
    showBannerAd();
    if(mMapView!=null){
        mMapView.onCreate(null);
        mMapView.onResume();
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    Intent i = getIntent();
    getNumber =i.getStringExtra("number");
    getLocation =i.getStringExtra("location");
    Log.e("location data",getLocation);
    getCounty= i.getStringExtra("country");
    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
    try {
        List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(getLocation, 1);
        Address add = list.get(0);
        latt = add.getLatitude();
        lon = add.getLongitude();


        if(getLocation.equals("null")) {
            //country lat long
            List<Address> list1 = gc.getFromLocationName(getCounty, 1);
            Address add1 = list1.get(0);
            latt = add1.getLatitude();
            lon = add1.getLongitude();

        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public void initCompnent() {
    mBannerAd= (AdView) findViewById(R.id.banner_AdView_m);
    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    mDeviceId=md5(android_id);
}
private void showBannerAd() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(mDeviceId)
            .build();
    mBannerAd.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```

i think here is issue but i don't know what this function does.

```
public String md5(String s) {
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0; i<messageDigest.length; i++)
            hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]));
        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

This is map function

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    /*MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setMapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(46.689247, -74.0444502)).title("tada"));*/

    mGoogleMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng Ny = new LatLng(latt,lon);
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Ny).title(getNumber));
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Ny,8));

}
```

Comment: Try checking  `List`  returned by `gc.getFromLocationName(getLocation, 1)` has something

Comment: as a side note. i'm not sure what your doing here: "if(getLocation.equals("null"))" but i can pretty sure its not what you want. to check for null you should just do getLocation == null

Comment: yes you are right gc.getFromLocationName(getLocation, 1) has issue. i am able to save crash but map  is still not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most likely in the line

```
Address add = list.get(0);
```

or

```
Address add1 = list1.get(0);
```

In both lists you try to get the first (0th) element without checking if there is actually anything in the list. You should before using the list check if it's empty using

```
if(!list.isEmpty())
```

As a side note as [Tomer Shemesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111447/tomer-shemesh) suggests the null check you perform also looks very iffy. Firstly you probably want to check `getLocation == null` instead. Secondly you probably want to do the check first before you try to use the `getLocation` string.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by updating API and also adding check of !list.isempty. thanks